# Passport.js Session is lost when CORS call in heroku but don't in local

Tags: angular, express, heroku

Hi everyone i've got an Angular 4 app calling an Express API in my local machine these apps are running in different ports (4200 and 3000). In my Express app i've configured:

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    console.log(req.headers.origin);
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', req.headers.origin);
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With, X-HTTP-Method-Override, Content-Type, Accept');
    if ('OPTIONS' == req.method) {
        res.sendStatus(200);
    } else {
        next();
    }
});
```

and my cookie config:

```
app.use(session({
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
    cookie: {
        httpOnly: true,
        expires: cookieExpirationDate // use expires instead of maxAge
    }
}));
```

In Angular 4 the requests are called with

```
this.http.post(environment.services + '/login', user, {withCredentials: true});
```

And everything works in localhost. But then this apps are deployed to different heroku apps. And there the session is setted in the first call but in other calls is not existing anymore. Do I miss something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decided to use Token-Based Authentication instead of Cookies. Inspired by this links: 
https://auth0.com/blog/angularjs-authentication-with-cookies-vs-token/
http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2016/08/16/angular-2-jwt-authentication-example-tutorial